# How to assign CLI variables from CLI output

Tags: bash, variables, scripting, command-line-interface

How do you arbitrarily extract output from CLI?

In my specific example (but the answer should generically apply to the whole) I'm trying to write a general-purpose deploy/scale script for a NodeJS/MongoDB technology stack ontop of AWS EC2/EBS with standard Ubuntu server OS (12.04). For now, I'm manually creating and attaching the EBS drives through the AWS Dashboard Console, but everything else should happen automatically, without ever having to SSH in and do stupid CLI (though eventually I want to automate the create&attach parts as well).

So first, I need to get a list of all the blocks `lsblk -l` that are EBS drives to mount.
Then I need to (on first time conditions) setup MDADM and LVM, however their commands assume that I know the names of the blocks, such as:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=10 --chunk=256 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdb4
```

and so on. This is great and easy... IF I am a human reading through the CLI output from lsblk. But how does one parse/extract and iterate through it dynamically? Somehow I need to do this (pseudo code):

```
$EBS_ARRAY = lsblk -l -list_the_names_of_blocks_not_mounted
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=10 --chunk=256 --raid-devices=EBS_ARRAY.length EBS_ARRAY.join(' ')
...rest of my script here...
```

You can obviously see that I am a javascript guy clueless about how to work dynamically with CLI without JSON and non-interactively (scripted). So... How on earth do you arbitrarily extract information out of CLI output, in an automated way, into variables?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally, it is not considered a good tone to start a question with a rant. Especially, if you rant against something other people like, and you're about to ask the very same people to help you out.

Comment: Besides, the rest of your script is elsewhere, but not here. And a example of `lsblk` output would help, too

Comment: 1. Part one of your question shows total ignorance in IT. 2. Have you tried googling it? Man 3 popen() would have helped you out.

Comment: try piping the output to a file so you can read it as a file

Comment: @Mouseroot, thanks. Once I have it in a file, are there any tools other than regular expressions that allow me to retrieve / extract arbitrary bits of the data? Like a tool that converts the output into JSON?

Comment: I checked the history of edits of this post and don't see any abusive edits. The only edit was removal of lots of unrelated rants. It is perfectly acceptable behavior on Stack OVerflow to remove such cruft and make the question better (see also http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse the output of a command in bash script there are several utilities like `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, as well as [shell builtins](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), that helps manipulating the strings to suit your needs.

On the other hand, you can't really do GUI-programming in bash script. For simple GUIs you may check `zenity` if you are under Gnome.

If you have to design advanced GUIs you may consider a programming language like `python` with `tkinter` or other graphic libraries.

If you have to run those CLI commands on a server you could write your application in python with `cgi`/`json` modules for the server side and javascript/ajax as main processing language.

By the way man pages are not that bad, and the argument syntax is largerly quite consistent through all the commands.

Comment: So you are basically saying you can't? Unless you do crazy regexp on random outputs or if you use another language that does that for you with a provided module?
Blah, if that is true, I'll mark your answer as correct and then resign myself to feeling doomed about CLI :P. Thanks.